# Xamarin Forms, Android Tablet USB Debugging problem

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I try to debug xamarin forms project on Android Tablet.Tablet's android version is Android 6.0.
Project Minimum Andriod version: Android 5.0
Target Android version: Android 9.0
and i am getting error:

```
ADB1000: Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: Permission denied
   at Mono.AndroidTools.Util.AggregateAsyncResult.CheckError(CancellationToken token) in E:\A\_work\412\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Util\AggregateAsyncResult.cs:line 72
   at Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbSyncClient.EndPushSyncItems(IAsyncResult result) in E:\A\_work\412\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Adb\AdbSyncClient.cs:line 1071
   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbClientTaskExtensions.InnerInvoke(TaskCompletionSource`1 tcs, Func`2 endMethod, IAsyncResult l) in E:\A\_work\412\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbClientTaskExtensions.cs:line 255
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<InstallAssemblies>d__117.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\412\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Sessions\AndroidDeploySession.cs:line 578
```

I tried to change target Android version to Android 6.0 but still i cannot debug it on tablet.
I am new on xamarin and android. Does anyone have any advice to fix this problem?

Comment: did you tried on emulator as well? create a tab emulator with same android version n try debugging it.

Comment: I cannot use emulator.I need to use  real device.

Comment: i'm saying just to check for error, if it comes for emulator as well... else try refreshing adb drivers, n disable & enable back usb debuggin on your tablet

Comment: I can't create emulator because of microsoft admin authorization.So i tried disable & enable usb debuggin but error continues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change Link assemblies to link all assemblies  and try again i think it will work for you right now for the debugging in emulator or device.

Comment: Hello thanks for your help, i changed linking to Sdk and User Assemblies(there is 3 option: None, Sdk only, Sdk and User Assemblies), and i got MSB6006: "java.exe"exited with code1 error.I tried to change java max heap Size '2G' but still got same error.

Comment: It worked when i delete bin folder in android project and clean all solution.